# How tell typescript that I use conditional type over union correctly?

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-statements, union

I have this base case:

```js
type Ids = "foo" | "bar" | "bazz";

interface IFoo {
  foo: string;
}

interface IBar {
  bar: number;
}

interface IBazz {
  bazz: boolean;
}

type Ret<T extends Ids> = T extends "foo" ? IFoo :
  T extends "bar" ? IBar :
  T extends "bazz" ? IBazz :
  never;

function a<T extends Ids>(id: T): Ret<T> {
  switch (id) {
    case "bar":
      return { bar: 1 };
    case "foo":
      return { foo: "foo" };
    case "bazz":
      return { bazz: true };
  }
}

const bar: IBar = a("bar");
const foo: IFoo = a("foo");
const bazz: IBazz = a("bazz");
```

As you can see, Typescript is not satisfied with my `a` function implementation. What should I change to compile this function but still keep guarantees in the last three statements?

playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJgZygXigIgGYHstqgH3QCMBDAJz0LVIC8a0BuAKCYEsA7YCMjEgY2gwAYjigBvJlCjYsALigJgZDgHNmAXxYcuPfoIBC5cZKiky89gFcAtkW4atnbrwGxDdY1No15RHABsIEnYHJlBIKAAlCGAAHgAVKAgADy52RFhEAD4UKESUtIzMHDwAflgRLChZE3zUiHSkanIytyMaqTrCpu9WmHcaapN2CAA3exYMS3Y+YFYsdigSBKT6xsyELIAKVjh5eIBKeWi4+JyJKQQAd1ZgPgALKB24A88pKD4SBGhmig73qRkGKWMiLMSmcjyACMUHUzABn2+6BkaH+AKBwBBYOkOHkxVwsPh70RP16aPeGKx4ghdHkSks0DhJk0miYfAWigh5jaZFyJC2vzQB2Y7PYnJk8mEolQ-PxQpFHOANJ8bQ8MoFvWFQA

Comment: Could you explain why you are doing *`T extends "foo"`*, i don't see any practical reason behind that. I feel like it should be `T === "foo"`

Comment: @Nicolas that's syntax of conditional types in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [open issue in TypeScript (see microsoft/TypeScript#33912)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) that the compiler is generally unable to verify that a particular function return value conforms to a conditional type that depends on an as-yet-unspecified generic type parameter, like `Ret<T>` inside the implementation of `a()` where `T` is unresolved.  This is related to the fact that TypeScript is unable to narrow type parameters via control flow analaysis] (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)), so checking `id` with a `switch`/`case` statement might narrow the type of `id` to, say, `"bar"`, but it does not narrow *the type parameter `T`* to `"bar"`, and thus it can't guarantee that `Ret<"bar">` is an acceptable output.

---

One thing you can do is accept that the compiler can't verify this for you and use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or [an overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to loosen the implementation typing enough to avoid the errors.  This will work, but the compiler is not guaranteeing type safety.  For example, with an overload:

```
function aOverload<T extends Ids>(id: T): Ret<T>;
function aOverload(id: Ids): Ret<Ids> {
  switch (id) {
    case "bar":
      return { bar: 1 };
    case "foo":
      return { foo: "foo" };
    case "bazz":
      return { bazz: true };
  }
}
```

now there's no error, and there's *some* type safety... you can't return a completely incorrect type like `{spazz: true}`,  but you can swap the `case`s around and it won't notice:

```
function aBadOverload<T extends Ids>(id: T): Ret<T>;
function aBadOverload(id: Ids): Ret<Ids> {
  switch (id) {
    case "bazz":
      return { bar: 1 };
    case "bar":
      return { foo: "foo" };
    case "foo":
      return { bazz: true };
  }
}
```

So you have to be careful.

---

Another solution to this particular case is to abandon conditional types in favor of generic indexing, like this:

```
interface RetMap {
  foo: IFoo,
  bar: IBar,
  bazz: IBazz;
}

function aGood<K extends keyof RetMap>(id: K): RetMap[K] {
  return {
    bar: { bar: 1 },
    foo: { foo: "foo" },
    bazz: { bazz: true }
  }[id];
}

const bar: IBar = aGood("bar");
const foo: IFoo = aGood("foo");
const bazz: IBazz = aGood("bazz");
```

The compiler is able to verify that what we are doing here is safe, because we're indexing into an object of type `RetMap` with the `id` key of type `K`.  Oh, and if you are unhappy that this version preemptively calculates return values it won't use, you could refactor to use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), which the compiler is also happy with:

```
function aGood<K extends keyof RetMap>(id: K): RetMap[K] {
  return {
    get bar() { return { bar: 1 } },
    get foo() { return { foo: "foo" } },
    get bazz() { return { bazz: true } }
  }[id];
}
```

---

Okay, hope that helps you proceed; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJgZygXigIgGYHstqgH3QCMBDAJz0LVIC8a0BuAKCYEsA7YCMjEgY2gwAYjigBvJlCjYsALigJgZDgHNmAXxYcuPfoIBC5cZKiky89gFcAtkW4atnbrwGxDdY1No15RHABsIEnYHJlBIKAAlCGAAHgAVKAgADy52RFhEAD4UKESUtIzMHDwAflgRLChZE3zUiHSkanIytyMaqTrCpu9WmHcaapN2CAA3exYmDEt2PmBWLHYoEgSk+sbMhCyAClY4eXiASnlouPiciSkEAHdWYD4ACyhduEPPKSg+EgRoZooOj5SMgxSxkJZiUzkeQARig6mYgK+P3QMjQAMBwOAoPB0hw8mKuDhCI+SN+vXRH0x2PEkLo8iUlmg8JMmk0UxmcwWSxIAHlxmR-FgSHBVgUGhl4FsXgdjlEYgkssxprN5otlnzuILhdLNrLTrFJRcTDc7o9nns3pcSd8yS0KUCQWCaWYYUSTFJSSiSvaoFSnRCZPjUW7ETbiCQ6Gj3ZTHTjvPSyIyQ3CmGzlZy1SRDHANQKhSKuuKkIadUcTvLzkqOarudnc1q4DrJXr5Yb3ib7k8Xpbo57mpGfX641CoLDmaHkX8o4CHVj-bi5F7CePrZPUYPY86Iz4oAymcTWY4dC5oKcALIkMDvQMVHAAGhMLraZAfXm38n624c6ZrywA4jgIoANJrN0UAANYQCAWAYHKwAXmAOx7PIQEtvBl4ANpAQAuu8Q7vFIKgxJCZDbJavqbhCT5jnCr4fERwALmRNL4QGeJLng6i0dGDG0jQzEQqxfEJkmXGaFI6gYXs2GhHwiyKCRH6GGQuQkABWCNlOhzMHJ7AKTewiiKgamAdsBJoNpTC6Qp8ZtB4xnqZpvSWVAQA)